# CSS: Fluid Sidebar - Fluid Content

Tags: html, css, xhtml

[image]

Everything's explained in the above image.

Basically, I need a sidebar div whose width expands according to the content inside of it and a `mainContent` that expands to the rest of the width of the window.

Comment: well that's nice. is there a question there? or just a work order? i'll answer a question, but i won't do your job.

Comment: If the sidebar expands according to its content, than it will expand to 100% width with some lines of text in it. Not really the definition of a sidebar either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do it.  @stefanw has a point, though.  The side bar will expand to the width of its text, and that means the text will not wrap.  I think that is probably not what you want.  Or maybe it is, if what you are putting in there is not vary wide, but isn't fixed either?

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
#overallWrapper div {
  background: #CCC;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 100%;
}
#sideBar {
  float: left;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="overallWrapper">
    <div id="sideBar">
      I need this to expand to the width of this text...
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      This should take the rest of the room, whatever's left...
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You could remove the overallWrapper, if you want.

Comment: Couldn't be more perfect! Thanks, you guys.

Answer (score 1):

If you're at all concerned about the width of the side bar on the left, you can apply the max-width css property to the left div, in case you aren't line breaking your inline content.

Also, make sure your doctype is strict if you're supporting ie7 with max-width.